# SVG: Text show to have spacing at top and bottom

Tags: javascript, svg, text

I am using a SVG to display a knock-out text template to create a rectangle that has text inside (that comes trough the mask). I want the mask text to match the given size and scale up properly, so that the text in charge does automatically is using the width and height it has for usage.

For longer paragraphs this work just fine but when the Text Content is not so long the logic scales up the text to its maximum width/height until it hits a border. See screenshot. But I do see that there is padding that I want to get rid of - how can I make the Text to fit the container fully?

To make it better visible I added a Text Element directly to the SVG so I can show the sizes of the Element. How can I get rid of this whitespace?

[Example with purple boxes that show whitespace in text element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOIKH.png)

This is an example with a longer text that works as expected:

```
<svg id="canvas-6" width="300px" height="75px" viewBox="0 0 300 75" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <text transform="translate(0,0)" class="knockout-text-value" id="fit-hidden-6" fill="#000" x="50%" y="50%" width="100%" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central" font-family="'Lato', sans-serif" font-size="60.785146891139px">TEST TEST</text>
    <rect id="fit-text-6" class="knockout-text-bg" width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" x="0" y="0" fill-opacity="1" stroke="black" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray="5,5" mask="url(#knockout-text-6)"></rect>
    <mask id="knockout-text-6">
        <rect width="300px" height="100%" fill="#fff" stroke="#000" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray="5,5" x="0" y="0"></rect>
        <text transform="translate(0,0)" class="knockout-text-value" id="fit-mask-6" fill="#000" x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central" font-family="'Lato', sans-serif" font-size="60.785146891139px">TEST TEST</text>
    </mask>
</svg>
```

This is an example that has the whitespace still inside its SVG canvas:

```
<svg id="canvas-5" width="300px" height="134px" viewBox="0 0 300 134" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <text transform="translate(0,0)" class="knockout-text-value" id="fit-hidden-5" fill="#000" x="50%" y="50%" width="100%" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central" font-family="'Lato', sans-serif" font-size="109.0909090909091px">TEST</text>
    <rect id="fit-text-5" class="knockout-text-bg" width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" x="0" y="0" fill-opacity="1" stroke="black" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray="5,5" mask="url(#knockout-text-5)"></rect>
    <mask id="knockout-text-5">
        <rect width="300px" height="100%" fill="#fff" stroke="#000" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray="5,5" x="0" y="0"></rect>
        <text transform="translate(0,0)" class="knockout-text-value" id="fit-mask-5" fill="#000" x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central" font-family="'Lato', sans-serif" font-size="109.0909090909091px">TEST</text>
    </mask>
</svg>
```

Comment: Without seeing code - it could be anything. Can you please post a minimum test case that shows the issue.

Comment: I added two examples

Comment: these look exactly the same - can you post the relevant CSS classes as well?

Comment: No CSS is involved - since the attributes are in the properties directly. Maybe pasted the same snippet twice?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `{ display: block }` on the svg.